# How to compare a list of string and a string, return the best match string from the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is on my second function code.

This is my code so far....
    def simi(d1,d2):
        dna_1 = d1.lower()
        dna_2 = d2.lower()
        lst = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(dna_1):
            if dna_1[i] == dna_2[i]:
                lst.append(1)
            i += 1
        return len(lst) / len(d1)

```
def match(list_1, d , s):
    dna = []
    for item in list_1:
        dna.append(simi(item, d))
        if max(dna) < s:
           return None
    return list_1[max(dna)]
```

Comment: Is you indentation intentionally messed up? I guess not....

Comment: You should define what "best match" is and how can it be measured.

Comment: If you go through your code step by step. It is pretty clear why you get no result. 'TACgtAttaCGT' matches 10 times in order. len(lst)/len(d1) returns 0, which you append. max(dna) returns 0, which is less than 0.8, and so it exits.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone, how does it return `0`?

Comment: len([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])/len('TACgtAttaCGT') = 0, which is assigned to dna (ie., dna = [0]). max(dna) = 0. What 0 are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, the first is you `return` in the loop before you have tried all the elements, secondly your function `simi(item, d)`returns a float if it works correctly so trying to index a list with a `float` will also fail. There is no way your code could do anything but error or return `None`.

I imagine you want to keep track of the best each iteration and return the item that is the best based on what it's `simi` distance calc is and if the `simi` is > s or else return None:

```
def match(list_1, d , s):
    best = None
    mx = float("-inf")
    for item in list_1:
        f = simi(item, d)
        if f > mx:
            mx = f
            best = item
    return best  if mx > s else None
```

You can also use range in simi instead of your while loop with a list comp:

```
def simi(d1,d2):
    dna_1 = d1.lower()
    dna_2 = d2.lower()
    lst = [1 for i in range(len(dna_1)) if dna_1[i] == dna_2[i] ]
    return len(lst) / len(dna_1)
```

But if you just want to add 1 each time they condition is True you can use sum:

```
def simi(d1,d2):
    dna_1 = d1.lower()
    dna_2 = d2.lower()
    sm = sum(dna_1[i] == dna_2[i] for  i in range(len(dna_1)))
    return sm / len(dna_1)
```

Comment: @ToffeeH, no worries, you could do it many other ways but this seemed the easiest to understand

Answer (score 0):

Using some builtins:

```
from functools import partial
similarity_with_sample = partial(simi, 'TACgtAcGaCGT')
```

Now similarity_with_sample is a function that takes one argument, and returns its similarity with 'TACgtAcGaCGT'.

Now use that as the key argument of the builtin max function:

```
best_match = max(list_of_samples, key=similarity_with_sample)
```

I'm not sure what your `s` variable is doing.